# Cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf, soap

I need to create a Web Service to interact with a government agency's front-end application, it will process request and responses in SOAP 1.1 XML.
(I'm new to WCF so am feeling my way.)

It will accept a POST request;

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What seems to be missing is the app.config of your console application. Your error message points to a mismatch between the client and the server.

Comment: There's no problem calling it from the console application.

As I said the problem comes about when calling it from 'Firefox's Poster tool or the SOAPUI interface'.

These types of calls reflect the way the service will be eventually called in real life.